# sbt : Is there a better way of structuring large build.sbt files

Tags: scala, build, sbt

## Problem description: large sbt file

Our current `build.sbt` spanns 250+ lines.

We have two problems:

### readability

current approach grouping of data and comments:

```
// Plugins ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)

// basic configuration : projects ///////////////////////////
name := """projectName"""

lazy val projectName =
 (project in file(".")).....
```

### logic reuse

We have some configuration logic we would like to share between different projects.

## Question

Is there a way to *include* other `*.sbt` files?
Or do you have a suggestion how to solve this problem *without resorting to write a sbt plugin*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Is there a way to include other `*.sbt` files?

Yes, you can simply put parts of your `build.sbt` file into other `*.sbt` files within your project root. SBT picks up all `*.sbt` files and merges them together, as there was only a single large file.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for.

Comment: An additional question: Is there a way to put them in some subfolder in order not to pollute the rooz directory ?

Comment: @AndreasNeumann Not that I'm aware of. But you can possibly tweak sbt to look for these files somewhere else. But then it's probably simpler to start using `project/*.scala` files.

Answer (score 5):

One thing you can do is to factor out parts of your build info into scala files in the project directory.

E.g. in our build we have a file *Dependencies.scala* in the *project* directory, which contains all dependencies of the various projects in one place:

```
object Dependencies {

  val akka_actor = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.13"

  // ...
}
```

This can then be imported from the build.sbt:

```
import Dependencies._

lazy val foo = Project(...) dependsOn (akka_actor, ...)
```

You can also put tasks and commands into objects in the project directory.

Update: One thing I often do when looking for inspiration about how to organize a build is to look at the build of complex, high-profile scala projects such as [akka](https://github.com/akka/akka). As you can see, they have moved a lot of logic into scala files in the [project directory](https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/project). The build itself is defined in [AkkaBuild.scala](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/project/AkkaBuild.scala).

Comment: Thank you. But the dependencies sadly are the smallest part of the problem :( and I am also dependant on values in the build file. Also an idea for this ?

Comment: You can put any val into scala objects in the project directory, not just dependencies. Is the issue that you have too many projects in the build.sbt? In that case you can use a Build.scala in the project directory and use all code organization tools of normal scala code.

Comment: So there is no way to semantically stay in `.sbt`-syntax and one has to resort to scala-code again.

Comment: Not that I know of. The projects I know that use build.sbt, such as spire and cats, have very long build.sbt Files.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and the support.